# how to insert multiple records alternatively into a single column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume I have two tables table1, table2. 
table1 having the data as follow

```
no
---------------
1
2
3
```

And table2 having the data as follow

```
no
-------------------
4
5
6
```

Now I want the query which is returns the result as follow

```
no
----------------
1
4
2
5
3
6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate a `ZIP` by applying a numbering rank the rows in each table and then union the two results together. I've offset table1's rank by 0.5 so that it interleaves correctly in the order.

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT "no", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "no" ASC) AS rnk
  FROM table1
),
cte2 AS
(
  SELECT "no", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "no" ASC) AS rnk
  FROM table2
  UNION SELECT "no", rnk - 0.5
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT "no"
FROM cte2
ORDER BY rnk ASC;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de54a/2)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to manipulate the `rownum` queried from each table:

```
SELECT   no 
FROM     (SELECT   no, rownum * 2 - 1 AS rn
          FROM     table1
          ORDER BY no ASC
          UNION ALL
          SELECT   no, rownum * 2 AS rn
          FROM     table2
          ORDER BY no ASC)
ORDER BY rn ASC
```